# Finding network type using MTU

Tags: networking, mtu

For example MTU of Ethernet is 1500.

Now if the packets are fragmented, then observed MTU will be the MTU of the router (i.e. less than 1500).

Is there any method to find out the type of the client network reliably and accurately?

Comment: Rather no. But ur question is to vague and fuzzy.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you want to know about PMTU Discovery.  See RFC 1191.

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1191.txt